# connecting roles to records

Tags: security, roles, access

In this tutorial, the instructor configures roles hierarchies, but in don't have the same options of what to do with them:

tutorial:
[Who Sees What: Record Access Via Roles (Lightning Experience)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZSw6s4hLS4&list=PL0AwNO1fHrWayVV-4_8vCziMp-zL218wt&index=6)

Her layout:
[image]

Mine, without the option connecting roles to records

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: likely the org wide defaults settings for Opportunity and Case are already more permissive than those rules and so there is no need to show the settings on that screen which grant additional access. Visit the Org Wide Defaults page for those objects and restrict access from its current setting and then come back to the role edit screen.

Comment: And you are correct: OWD as private, then increasing access with roles, does the trick. Thanks!